# How to support for common RESTful HTTP response codes in AWS Chalice+API Gateway?

Tags: python, aws-api-gateway, chalice

I want to handle 401, 500 error with custom response. Flask provides a nice way,

```
@app.errorhandler(401)
```

Is there any similar way for Chalice? I changed the Gateway Response from API Gateway via console and everytime I deploy my chalice app, I need to change it manually. Is there any automated way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Chalice provides a built in set of exception classes that map to common HTTP errors.

See the [documentation](https://aws.github.io/chalice/topics/views.html#error-handling)

Comment: I am looking for something similar to Middleware or decorator that will handle certain error globally. The solution you suggested is not customizable. Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: I see. Well AFAIK there is nothing built into chalice that does that, but I could be wrong

Comment: Middleware & Decorator can be solution but I feel like there is a lack in documentation. Seems like I need to dig deeper. Thanks for your suggestion.  

https://github.com/aws/chalice/pull/1549
https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/1282